# save fields from mat file as csv files in a loop

Tags: matlab, csv, save, structure, field

I have a .mat file `file_0_50_abcdef_ft.mat` with 15 fields (e.g., `cgb`, `stpAB`, `stpAC`, `stAB`, etc.), and each of these 15 fields is a structure. 
I need to extract one field from the first structure: `cgb.ch`, and two fields (with the same label) from the other 14 structures (i.e., `poscllabmat` and `negcllabmat`).

Once I extract them, I need to save them as separate .csv files. The output I would like to obtain is for example: `cgb_ch.csv`, `stpAB_poscllabmat_0_50.csv`, `stpAB_negcllabmat_0_50.csv`, `stpAC_poscllabmat_0_50.csv`, `stpAC_negcllabmat_0_50.csv`, and so on.

What would be the best way to achieve this?
I will need to do it for several .mat files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [create matrix based on different structures of mat file in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47292228/create-matrix-based-on-different-structures-of-mat-file-in-matlab)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop over the vars / field combinations, Create a filename, uses dynamic field names to access the data and feed it to `csvwrite`.

Something like this:

```
temp = load('file_0_50_abcdef_ft.mat');
varList  = {'cgb', 'stpAB', 'stpAC'};
subField = {{'ch'}, {'poscllabmat', 'negcllabmat'}, {'poscllabmat', 'negcllabmat'}};
for j = 1:numel(varList)
    for k = 1:numel(subField{j})
        fileName = [varList{j} '_' subField{j}{k} '.csv'];
        csvwrite(fileName,temp.(varList{j}).(subField{j}{k}));
    end
end
```

Note: there is no error checking at all.  If your mat file is missing a variable or one of the structures is missing a field then it will error.